# How to directly call python function from web through Apache

Tags: python, apache

I'm from the PHP universe and completely new to Python. Python really is easy but trouble starts when trying to create some simple web pages. I read something about calling Python functions through the web browser should be possible. This is what I am talking about:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import cgi;
import cgitb;cgitb.enable()
import requests

print ("Content-Type: text/html\r\n")

print("<html><body>Test</body></html>")

def home():
        print("<html><body>Another Test</body></html>")
```

Opening http://localhost/index.py returns "Test". Calling http://localhost/index.py/home returns the same, however, I want it to return "Another Test".

Any ideas how this could be accomplished? Running apache2 and mod_python. Do I need mod_rewrite for this?

PS.: I don't want to use any frameworks like Django, all I need is a simple web form to provide input for my scripts.

Comment: You will need to provide an argument to your script, and show a page based on that.

Comment: You mean passing GET variables to the script? That's what I'm used to from PHP, however, I've seen an example on functions being directly called that way. Can't find it anymore and I may have misunderstood how it worked. Considered this a feature of mod_python.